# Why would cursor.with_rows return `True` but fetch_one return `None`?

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

Given this partial function (and Python 2.7, mysql-connector 2.1.6):

```
def get_target_item(self, query, key):
    self._target_query.execute(query, (key,))
    if self._target_query.with_rows:
        raw_item = self._target_query.fetchone()
```

I expected raw_item to always be non-`None`, but it turns out that it is sometimes `None`.

If I add this:

```
        if not raw_item:
            print "Could not find find target item for query {0} and key {1}".format( query, key )
```

I can see this gets printed sometimes. And if I run the same query myself, I can see that the query does not return rows for the specified key. So why does `with_rows` suggest that it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is what the documentation for `.with_rows`says:

> Returns whether the cursor could have rows returned
>
> This property returns True when column descriptions are available and
>   possibly also rows, which will need to be fetched.

As you can see, as long as the `description` attribute of the cursor is not `None`, `with_rows` will return `True`.

If you are using a buffered cursor, you can check the cursor's `rowcount` attribute to make sure that it is greater than `0`. That should constitute a better check.

I hope this proves useful.